# MYSQL entries from one table that appear most often in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables, authors and books

authors contains the unique id authorId

books also contains this as a foreign key

I need to know the authors with the most number of books. If 2 or more authors are tied for the greatest number of books, I need to show both authors

I have been able to achieve this by first getting the maximum count

```
SELECT @maxCount := (MAX(counter)) FROM (SELECT count(*) AS counter FROM books GROUP BY authorId) AS counts;
```

and then using it to get the Ids with that count as part of my author selection

```
SELECT * 
FROM authors 
WHERE authorId IN (
    SELECT authorId 
    FROM books 
    GROUP BY authorId 
    HAVING COUNT(*) = @maxCount
);
```

I've been told that I am not allowed to use variables and that what I've done is horribly inefficient if the tables grow very large.

Am I missing something obvious here? Is there a way to do this in a single statement without a variable (or temp table), and without having to select/group the entire books table twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT author, COUNT(*)
FROM authors
JOIN books
ON authors.authorId=books.AuthorId
GROUP BY author
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Will give you a list ordered by the number of books for each author. I don't have an instance nearby to test, and tend to steer clear of embedded variables but expect something like....

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT author
  , @maxcount:=IF(COUNT(*)>@maxcount,COUNT(*), @maxcount) 
  , COUNT(*) AS cnt
  FROM authors
  JOIN books
  ON authors.authorId=books.AuthorId
  GROUP BY author
  ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
) ilv
WHERE cnt=@maxcount;
```

Performance still sucks with large datasets (even with the right indexes). If you have to run this query frequently with >100,000 records, then you might consider denormalizing your data.

Comment: This gives me all authors and book counts, when I want to limit to only the authors with the most books.

Comment: ...I was still typing!

Comment: ....but if you know that you are unlikely to have more than, say, 20 authors with the same max count, you could just append LIMIT 0,20 to the first query (and ignore those with ferwer than max). It won't help with the performance but it'll make the code more readable.

Comment: The second query fixes my issue with selecting and grouping books twice and provides the result set I expect. From what I have now been told by a co-worker, mysql lacks the analytic functions required to do this without a temp table or variable. I don't know if this is true, but I'm going to assume it is and go with your answer. Thanks.

Comment: No, SQL lacks the analytical functions required for this type of problem. MySQL provides variables (and procedural SQL) to address this.

Answer (score 0):

Symcbean solution is great... you can add Limit 1 to it, to get only one instance.

```
SELECT A.authorId, A.name, COUNT(*) AS num_books
FROM authors A
INER JOIN books B
ON A.authorId=B.AuthorId
GROUP BY A.authorId, A.name
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

But if you want to get all the authors who share the max number of books, your best bet is to store the max(count) in a variable, or temp table and use it in second query.

for example, you can store the info in the following temp table

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS maxBooks AS (
    SELECT authorId, COUNT(*)  AS num_books
    FROM books 
    GROUP BY authorId
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
    LIMIT 1
)
```

now you can join it to your table to get counts which are equal to max count